# Mostrar ArrayList que contiene un objeto

Tags: java, arraylist

Estoy creando un programa de Bingo y en la clase Bingo he creado un constructor que inicializa un ArrayList de enteros desde el numero 1 hasta el 99. El problema lo tengo en que no se como mostrar el contenido de ese ArrayList al crear el objeto Bingo en la clase main. No se si no he rellenado bien la lista o que está pasando. Adjunto el codigo de la clase Bingo. Gracias de antemano.

```
package Ejercicio1;
```

import java.util.*;

public class Bingo {

```
public static final int BOLA_MAYOR = 99;
public static final int TAMAÑO_CARTON = 25;
private ArrayList<Integer> bombo;
private ArrayList<Integer> bolasExtraidas;
private int ultimaBola;

public Bingo() {
    this.bombo=new ArrayList<Integer>(BOLA_MAYOR);
    for (int i=0;i<this.bombo.size()-1;i++) {
        this.bombo.add(i);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes imprimir el contenido del ArrayList en la consola, puedes hacer un metodo para esto, por ejemplo:

```
class Bingo {

    public static final int BOLA_MAYOR = 99;
    public static final int TAMAÑO_CARTON = 25;
    private ArrayList<Integer> bombo;
    private ArrayList<Integer> bolasExtraidas;
    private int ultimaBola;

    public Bingo() {
        this.bombo = new ArrayList<Integer>(BOLA_MAYOR);
        for (int i = 0; i < BOLA_MAYOR; i++) {
            this.bombo.add(i);
        }
    }

    public void print() {
        for (int i = 0; i < BOLA_MAYOR; i++) {
            int item = this.bombo.get(i);
            System.out.println(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Para ejecutarlo:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bingo bingo = new Bingo();
        bingo.print();
    }
}
```

Ademas si te das cuenta cambie el codigo

```
for (int i=0;i<this.bombo.size()-1;i++)
```

Por

```
for (int i = 0; i < BOLA_MAYOR; i++)
```

Debido a que al inicializar el ArrayList solo estas definiendo la capacidad, y el metodo `size()` obtiene la cantidad de elementos que pose el Array,
aca hay una buena discusión de esto [hilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896758/initial-size-for-the-arraylist).

Ademas de te recomiendo aprender a debugear tus programas, con esto podrás inspeccionar todo tipo de cosas, como los valores de tus variables y muchos! mas te dejo un [tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-your-first-java-application.html)

Comment: Con esto quieres decir que al usar el size() no rellena nada porque aun no hay ningun elemento en la lista y puesto que el la lista esta vacia cuenta el tamaño como 0?. Muchas gracias, le echare un ojo a esos hilos para enterarme bien del tema.